# Conditional filtering on a grouped variable, based on row length of group

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, subset, do.call

A simple query which I can't get my head around:

Sample dataset:

```
   ACH_DATE   CODE
1 31OCT2018 A81001
2 31JAN2019 A81001
3 31OCT2018 A81002
4 31JAN2019 A81002
5 31OCT2018 A81003
6 31JAN2019 A81004
```

I want to `group_by` on the `CODE` variable, and filter on `ACH_DATE`, whereby if a group has more than one row, remove the row where `ACH_DATE == "31OCT2018"`.

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(ACH_DATE = c("31OCT2018", "31JAN2019", "31OCT2018", 
"31JAN2019", "31OCT2018", "31JAN2019"), CODE = c("A81001", "A81001", 
"A81002", "A81002", "A81003", "A81004")), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We group by 'CODE', create a logical vector with number of rows and 'ACH_DATE'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(CODE) %>% 
  filter((n() > 1 &  ACH_DATE != "31OCT2018") | n() == 1)
```